# Can't install PyQt4 in OS X 10.10.5 Yosemite with Python 3.6

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

Today I made an attempt to install mayavi which requires vtk. I finally got vtk to install and be importable but ruined my Python 3.4 environment in the process. It's about time I moved to 3.6 anyway, so that's not a huge problem, but what is a huge problem is not being able to install PyQt4 now.

I got Qt (5.7.1) and SIP (4.19) working with only a bit of trouble but I'm at a roadblock with PyQt4. I have tried both `brew install pyqt` and also attempted to build it from source. In both cases, this is the result:

```
Determining the layout of your Qt installation...
/usr/local/opt/qt5/bin/qmake -spec macx-g++ -o qtdirs.mk qtdirs.pro
make -f qtdirs.mk
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/g++ -c -pipe -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.8 -O2-std=gnu++11 -Wall -W -fPIC -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.7.1_1/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.7.1_1/mkspecs/macx-g++ -F/usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.7.1_1/lib -o qtdirs.o qtdirs.cpp
In file included from qtdirs.cpp:1:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.7.1_1/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/QCoreApplication:1:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.7.1_1/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qcoreapplication.h:43:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.7.1_1/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qglobal.h:1145:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.7.1_1/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qatomic.h:46:
/usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.7.1_1/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qbasicatomic.h:61:4: error: "Qt requires C++11 support"
#  error "Qt requires C++11 support"
   ^
```

In response, I tried `export CXXFLAGS=-std=c++11` and (both separately and together) `export CPPFLAGS=-std=c++11` which didn't help. I also tried adding the following to the `qtdirs.pro` file but it made no difference:

```
QMAKE_LFLAGS += -stdlib=libc++
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -stdlib=libc++
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -mmacosx-version-min=10.7
QMAKE_LFLAGS += -mmacosx-version-min=10.7
```

What's the next step?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be very simple to fix. I downloaded and installed `qt-opensource-mac-4.8.7.dmg` so that the qmake in my /usr/bin is for Qt 4.8.7, then simply going into the `PyQt4_gpl_mac-4.12` and typing `python configure.py && make` successfully completed.